# int to byte[] consistency over network

Tags: c#, serialization, endianness

I have a struct that gets used all over the place and that I store as byteArray on the hd and also send to other platforms.

I used to do this by getting a string version of the struct and using getBytes(utf-8) and getString(utf-8) during serialization. With that I guess I avoided the little and big endian problems?

However that was quite a bit of overhead and I am now using this:

```
 public static explicit operator byte[] (Int3 self)
    {

        byte[] int3ByteArr = new byte[12];//4*3
        int x = self.x;
        int3ByteArr[0] = (byte)x;
        int3ByteArr[1] = (byte)(x >> 8);
        int3ByteArr[2] = (byte)(x >> 0x10);
        int3ByteArr[3] = (byte)(x >> 0x18);
        int y = self.y;
        int3ByteArr[4] = (byte)y;
        int3ByteArr[5] = (byte)(y >> 8);
        int3ByteArr[6] = (byte)(y >> 0x10);
        int3ByteArr[7] = (byte)(y >> 0x18);
        int z = self.z;
        int3ByteArr[8] = (byte)z;
        int3ByteArr[9] = (byte)(z >> 8);
        int3ByteArr[10] = (byte)(z >> 0x10);
        int3ByteArr[11] = (byte)(z >> 0x18);

        return int3ByteArr;
    }



public static explicit operator Int3(byte[] self)
        {

            int x = self[0] + (self[1] << 8) + (self[2] << 0x10) + (self[3] << 0x18);
            int y = self[4] + (self[5] << 8) + (self[6] << 0x10) + (self[7] << 0x18);
            int z = self[8] + (self[9] << 8) + (self[10] << 0x10) + (self[11] << 0x18);

            return new Int3(x, y, z);

        }
```

It works quite well for me, but I am not quite sure how little/big endian works,. do I still have to take care of something here to be safe when some other machine receives an int I sent as a bytearray?

Comment: Use `IPAddress.HostToNetwork` method. Currently if you software will be running on big-enndian system - you end up with little-enndian bytes sended over network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current approach will not work for the case when your application running on system which use Big-Endian. In this situation you don't need reordering at all.

You don't need to reverse byte arrays by your self
And you don't need check for endianess of the system by your self

Static method `IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder` will convert integer to the integer with  big-endian order.

Static method `IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder` will convert integer to the integer with order your system using

Those methods will check for Endianness of the system and will do/or not reordering of integers.

For getting bytes from integer and back use `BitConverter`

```
public struct ThreeIntegers
{
    public int One;
    public int Two;
    public int Three;
}

public static byte[] ToBytes(this ThreeIntegers value )
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[12];
    byte[] bytesOne = IntegerToBytes(value.One);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(bytesOne, 0, bytes, 0, 4);

    byte[] bytesTwo = IntegerToBytes(value.Two);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(bytesTwo , 0, bytes, 4, 4);

    byte[] bytesThree = IntegerToBytes(value.Three);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(bytesThree , 0, bytes, 8, 4);

    return bytes;
} 

public static byte[] IntegerToBytes(int value)
{
    int reordered = IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(value);
    return BitConverter.GetBytes(reordered);
}
```

And converting from bytes to struct

```
public static ThreeIntegers GetThreeIntegers(byte[] bytes)
{
    int rawValueOne = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
    int valueOne = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(rawValueOne);

    int rawValueTwo = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 4);
    int valueTwo = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(rawValueTwo);

    int rawValueThree = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 8);
    int valueThree = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(rawValueThree);

    return new ThreeIntegers(valueOne, valueTwo, valueThree);
}
```

If you will use `BinaryReader` and `BinaryWriter` for saving and sending to another platforms then BitConverter and byte array manipulating can be dropped off.

```
// BinaryWriter.Write have overload for Int32
public static void SaveThreeIntegers(ThreeIntegers value)
{
    using(var stream = CreateYourStream())
    using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
    {
        int reordredOne = IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(value.One);
        writer.Write(reorderedOne);

        int reordredTwo = IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(value.Two);
        writer.Write(reordredTwo);

        int reordredThree = IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(value.Three);
        writer.Write(reordredThree);
    }
}
```

For reading value

```
public static ThreeIntegers LoadThreeIntegers()
{
    using(var stream = CreateYourStream())
    using (var writer = new BinaryReader(stream))
    {
        int rawValueOne = reader.ReadInt32();
        int valueOne = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(rawValueOne);

        int rawValueTwo = reader.ReadInt32();
        int valueTwo = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(rawValueTwo);

        int rawValueThree = reader.ReadInt32();
        int valueThree = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(rawValueThree);
    }
}
```

Of course you can refactor methods above and get more cleaner solution.
Or add as extension methods for `BinaryWriter` and `BinaryReader`.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.. However I am not happy with the overhead of allocating 3 extra bytearrays for each conversion. Would I also be safe if I do a check for if(bitconverter.islittleendian) on both the endcode and decode and then just shift the bytes in reversed order? (not 0..3 but 3..0 for each int)

Comment: @user3488765, if you will use `BinaryReader/Writer` for writing values to the stream you don't need byte array at all. Main point of my answer was that `IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder` will reorder bytes in correct order.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you do. With changes endianness your serialization which preserves bit ordering will run into trouble.

Take the int value 385

In a bigendian system it would be stored as

000000000000000110000001

Interpreting it as littleendian would read it as 
100000011000000000000000
And reverse translate to 8486912

If you use the BitConverter class there will be a book property desiring the endianness of the system. The bitconverter can also produce the bit arrays for you.

You will have to decide to use either endianness and reverse the byte arrays according to the serializing or deserializing systems endianness.

The [description on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) is actually quite detailed. Here they use `Array.Reverse` for simplicity. I am not certain that your casting to/from byte in order to do the bit manipulation is in fact the fastest way of converting, but that is easily benchmarked.

Comment: So I can check if a system is little endian and when it is,.. I do what I do above, but not from indexes 0..3 but 3..1?

Comment: That sounds reasonable, yes. But remember to make the same checks on reverse translation.